# Object Properties From Custom Classes in iOS

Tags: ios, class, properties

This should be easy - but I am scratching my head over it. Here's the problem:

I have a custom class that I import into my MainViewController.h file. The class contains a bunch of properties and a few methods.

I instantiate an object of this class in the ViewDidLoad section, and can run any of the methods or alter the properties on this object at will... they work fine as long as I stay within the ViewDidLoad section.

I created a button with which I wish to activate one of my custom class methods on this object, but the IBAction section seems out of scope, as it doesn't see the object created in ViewDidLoad at all.

Can someone point me in the right direction to enable these two areas to see eachother?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you creating a property for the instance of your custom class? (obvious question but it doesn't sound like you are)

Comment: Let's say I have an a object called 'elvis' that I instantiate in ViewDidLoad. The class has a property named 'weight' and a method to display that weight both defined in the class. I instantiate the object, and setWeight to 250. I can use the displayWeight method right after and it works fine in the ViewDidLoad; however, if I create a button as -(IBAction)showWeight:(id)sender {
    [elvis displayWeight];
}, it doesn't recognize the 'elvis' object. Do I need to add corresponding properties to the MainViewController files?

Comment: As @skinnyTOD said, do you create a property for the instance?  In your view controller .h, you should declare a property (strong) for elvis.  If you don't do this, then elvis will be deallocated when viewDidLoad completes.